# google_map_flutter how to get visible region when zoom or move

Tags: flutter

I am using `google_map_flutter` in my flutter project and would like to know how to get the visible region (LatLngBounds) when I zoom the map? I want to use the bounds to filter the loaded item from backend.

I try to save the GoogleMapController to a field in my widget but it becomes null in `onCameraMove` callback function.

Shall we calculate the visible region by ourselves with zoom value contained in `CameraPosition`? If so, does anyone have the equation to calculate that?

Thank you

```
GoogleMapController? _googleMapController;

GoogleMap(
        markers: ctrl.markers,
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: ctrl.initialCameraPosition,
        zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
          _googleMapController = controller;
          final LatLngBounds bounds = await controller.getVisibleRegion();
          await ctrl.listForMap(bounds);
        },
        onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position) async {
          if (_googleMapController != null) {   // <------always null
             print(await _googleMapController!.getVisibleRegion());
          }

          print(position); // <---only contains zoom value
        },
      )
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I get it working and the answer is actually right in the readme of google_map_flutter.

In GetControler (I am using GetX), I have

```
final Completer<GoogleMapController> googleMapController = Completer();
```

Then in the view, I have

```
GoogleMap(
          markers: ctrl.markers,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(0, 20),
          initialCameraPosition: ctrl.initialCameraPosition,
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
            ctrl.googleMapController.complete(controller);
            final LatLngBounds bounds = await controller.getVisibleRegion();
            print(
                'north east: ${bounds.northeast.latitude}, ${bounds.northeast.longitude}');
            print(
                'north east: ${bounds.southwest.latitude}, ${bounds.southwest.longitude}');
            await ctrl.listForMap(bounds);
          },
          onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position) async {
            GoogleMapController googleMapController =
                await ctrl.googleMapController.future;
            print("onCameraMove");
            LatLngBounds bounds = await googleMapController.getVisibleRegion();
            print("========================================");
            print(bounds.northeast);
            print(bounds.southwest);
          },
          onCameraIdle: () async {
            GoogleMapController googleMapController =
                await ctrl.googleMapController.future;
            print("onCameraIdle");
            LatLngBounds bounds = await googleMapController.getVisibleRegion();
            print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            print(bounds.northeast);
            print(bounds.southwest);
          }),
```

When I zoom the map, `onCameraMove` would be called multiple time with the changing bounds and `onCameraIdle` is called once at the end of the zoom action.

Answer (score 0):

in your code you are not creating new instance for completer.

you can instantiate new instance of Completer() while defining the variable name.

```
Completer<GoogleMapController> controllerCompleter = Completer();
```

then to use `.getVisibleRegion()` your code should look like this:

```
final LatLngBounds mapBounds = await GoogleMapsFlutterPlatform.instance
                                    .getVisibleRegion(mapId: _mapId!);
```